# How do I change the background color of mat-drawing-container?

Tags: angular

I am trying to change the background color of the sidebar of my website, but it won't change from its default color. I am new and trying to learn angular so forgive me if there is an obvious answer to this problem.

Components.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  template: `
    
  <mat-drawer-container class ="example-container">
  <img class = "waitwell-logo" src="assets/waitwell.jpg">
  logo
  </mat-drawer-container>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class SidebarComponent {

}
```

styles.scss:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }

.example-container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #848383;

}

.waitwell-logo {
  min-height: 60px;
  max-height: 90px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

This is what I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2X7t.png)
But I want the sidebar to be white, not grey.

Answer (score 0):

One of [Angular Material Sidenav examples](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples#sidenav-drawer-overview) show that you could add additional selectors inside `mat-drawer-container` - like `mat-drawer` and `mat-drawer-content`.
Your case needs an additional nesting of `mat-drawer` with custom class, like below, which would allow to style it directly

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
  <mat-drawer class="my-sample-background-class" mode="side" opened><img class="waitwell-logo" src="assets/waitwell.jpg">
  </mat-drawer>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

You need to update Your `example-container` class styles to meet the new criteria